# Code Contracts: validating string characters

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm using code contracts to validate an input string. The input contract, in plain English:

- The string has to start with a letter (case insensitive)
- The string can only contain letters, numbers or hyphens

Converted to code, I end up with a constructor that looks like this...

```
private readonly string ruleName;

protected Lexer(string ruleName)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ruleName));
    Contract.Requires(char.IsLetter(ruleName, index: 0));
    Contract.Requires(Contract.ForAll(ruleName.ToCharArray(), c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-'));
    this.ruleName = ruleName;
}
```

Corresponding class invariant...

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    Contract.Invariant(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ruleName));
    Contract.Invariant(char.IsLetter(this.ruleName, index: 0));
    Contract.Invariant(Contract.ForAll(this.ruleName.ToCharArray(), c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '-'));
}
```

The last contract seems to confuse the static contract checker tool. The static checker claims that it cannot prove that the predicate is true for each character in the return value of `ruleName.ToCharArray()`.

This upsets me, because `ToCharArray()` is deterministic. Strings are immutable, so calling `ToCharArray()` on a string will always return the same value, and so the predicate will always hold.

Is there a way to express my string validation in a way that the static contract checker can prove?

Comment: If there is no way to satisfy the static checker, I'll also accept answers that show me how to suppress the compile-time warnings that are generated.

Comment: Similar question was already asked, try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5265344/4585429

Comment: Are there any specific constraints on what method you (can) use? Because personally I would be inclined to use a regular expression to validate. Which should work just fine with code contracts. I think. Never used code contracts myself but I see no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: I have a strong aversion to regular expressions. I don't know if code contracts can check regex at compile-time, but I'd be surprised if it did.

Comment: By the way, my validation works fine as it is. My only problem is that the cc plugin generates warnings that are not justified when compile-time code analysis is enabled.

Comment: Why the aversion? You can roll all 3 validations into 1 regular expression, seems far more efficient to me.

Comment: A regular expression doesn't tell you _why_ the input doesn't match. In my validation, the stack trace will tell you exactly which rule caused the exception.

Comment: Also, the point of using code contracts is to document the preconditions that a calling program should check for. If my precondition contains a regular expression, then the calling program should validate its inputs using the same regular expression before making the call. I **really** do not want to force users of my library to regex-validate their inputs.

Comment: Then I would suggest we figure out why exactly it cannot prove. Have you since tried anything yourself? At the risk of sounding obvious (again, never used code contracts myself) but may using a literal hyphen is causing some form of incongruity and the character code for one should be used instead? Just a thought, mind you. Would have to toy with the construct of code contracts myself to see what is going on in more detail and I have 0 use for them.

Comment: The problem is that the plugin doesn't understand that `ToCharArray()` will always return the same characters. When I require that a predicate holds for all characters in the array, the plugin gets suspicious and tells me that the conditions are unproven for the given string, even after passing the validation.

Comment: After some research on best practices regarding Code Contracts in conjunction with input validation and some research on their support in Mono and thus the crossplatform viability of this kind of input validation I can only arrive at the conclusion that it is neither recommended nor wise.

Comment: Well... the contracts that I wrote still work at runtime. Mono shouldn't have problems executing that code, although I have no way to verify that right now. I'm really just super annoyed with the GUI tools telling me that my contracts can't be proven even though they __can__ be proven.